# adding html attributes to rails form helper

Tags: html, forms, devise, helper

I am customize thing default Devise new.html.erb in Session View so it generate Html code like

```
  <form class="form-signin" role="form">
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <label class="checkbox">
      <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me
    </label>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign in</button>
  </form>
```

I have added the line :html => `{:class => 'form-signin', :role => 'form'}` to the code below.

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => session_path(resource_name),
    :html => {:class => 'form-signin', :role => 'form'}) do |f| %>
  <div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email  %></div>
  <div><%= f.label :password %><br />
  <%= f.password_field :password %></div>

  <% if devise_mapping.rememberable? -%>
    <div><%= f.check_box :remember_me %> <%= f.label :remember_me %></div>
  <% end -%>

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign in" %></div>
<% end %>

<%= render "devise/shared/links" %>
```

I am not sure what to do next to modify

```
<div><%= f.label :email %><br />
  <%= f.email_field :email  %></div>
```

so it generates this: `<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required autofocus>`

??
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<%= f.text_field :email, placeholder: "Email address",
required: true, autofocus: true  %>
```

Should work.